# pass "calendar.selectedvalue" in querystring from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to pass `calendar1.Selecteddate` in a `query string` from `gridview` in one page to another `gridview` (I have written `sqlquery` in that `gridview`) in another page. As seen in the below code I tried passing it but this did not work. Can anyone tell me how to pass the selected date from `calendar` in `query string`

```
      <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="LocalIP" 
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="DailyResults.aspx?
           Terms={0}&column=LocalIP&    
               startdate=Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.Date.ToShortDateString()
                DataTextField="LocalIP" HeaderText="User" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to build your URL string in the code-behind, instead of building it in the markup.

Override the RowDataBound method on the GridView and build the hyperlink programmatically:

```
protected override gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  HyperLink hl = new Hyperlink();
  hl.NavigateUrl = string.Format("DailyResults.aspx?Terms={0}&column=LocalIP&startdate={1}", localIp, Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.Date.ToShortDateString());
  .. set other hyperlink fields ..
  e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(hl);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've provided it would treat that calendar part of the string as a literal and pass the exact value you have typed.
In order to obtain the data using you would need to do something similar to:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="<%=GetSelectedDate()%>....
```

where this is a method on the code behind class (or you could use a property) that creates the string you intend, including the {0} placeholder for the LocalIP bound data field.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the calendar selected value has not changed since the gridview was rendered.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="LocalIP" 
     DataNavigateUrlFormatString='<%# "DailyResults.aspx?Terms={0}&column=LocalIP&startdate=" + Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.Date.ToShortDateString() %> DataTextField="LocalIP" HeaderText="User" />
```